# Mesh arms twisted when connected to armature

Tags: modeling, mesh, armature

The arm of my mesh gets twisted by my armature, and I cannot rotate the bone that is causing it:

[image]

I cannot find anything online to help with this, not sure what is wrong.

http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=52715 (Models/Characters/Armature)

EDIT:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Your arms IKs have their pole targets set to your legs pole targets.
2. You forgot to set the pole angle to 180° on your right arm as you did on the left side.
3. Your Hand.R bone is rotated in pose mode. Go in pose mode and hit <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to reset its rotation.

For your IK chain to fold the right way, there are two things you can do:

- Already fold the chain the way it's meant to fold in edit mode (just a little), so the IK solver knows in which direction to work;
  [image]
- If it's not enough, select the bone with the IK constraint in Pose mode, head over to the Bone tab, Inverse Kinematics panel, and lock the local axes you don't want that IK chain to fold on. Here for your left arm it's the Z axis you want to fold on, so lock the others. That's also where you can indicate minimum/maximum angles so your character don't look like he brokes his bones all the time.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I appriciate you trying to help!

1. From what I can see, they are not connected, but they are connected to the master bone at the bottom as instrcuted in the tutorial I followed, is that wrong?
2. What is pole angle? I can see that under transform, they all have the same rotation, is pole angle something else?
3. Resetting all pose rotations made it worse, now the wrists are also rotated =/

Comment: Ah I found pole angle, seems to have solved the twisting by setting it to 90 degress. However, now my elbows dont bend inwards anymore, they bend downwards.

Comment: Select your lower arm bones in pose mode and watch their IK constraints. The bones set as pole targets are wrong. Fix that, then the pole target, then the arm rotation, and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I added an EDIT to my post that shows the result from this. The twisting is gone which is awesome! However, as you can see, the elbow bends downwards still =/

Comment: Double check the roll on the elbow bones. That would change their axes